# How to access RadioButtonList items in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have a RadioButtonList in C#.  This list contains a selector for favorite fruits (sorted alphabetically):

```
Favorite Fruits:
    ( )  Apple
    ( )  Banana
    ( )  Pineapple
    ( )  Pomegranate
```

...and let's say I have a method that prints out facts about your favorite fruit at the click of a button:

```
private void FruitFactsButton_OnClick(arguments){

    switch( favoriteFruits.SelectedIndex ){

        case 0:      // Apple
          doStuffForApple();
        break;

        case 1:      // Banana
          doStuffForBanana();
        break;

        case 2:     // Pineapple
          doStuffForPineapple();
        break;

        case 3:    // Pomegranate
          doStuffForPomegranate();
        break;
    }

}
```

Let's say there are dozens of switch/cases in my codebase that depend on which `favoriteFruits` element is selected.

If I decide to add an element to this list (not at the end), I'd have to manually find every switch/case and update the indices (adding `Banana` would force me to +1 the indices of `Kiwi`, `Pineapple`, and `Pomegranate`, if I wanna keep everything alphabetical.)

**Is there a way I can reference the indices as an enumerated value?**  As in, is there something that I can do that's similar to this?

```
    switch( favoriteFruits.SelectedIndex ){
        case favoriteFruits.getEnumConstants.APPLE:
            doStuffForApple();
        break;
```

I know there's a `RadioButtonList.Items` accessor, but I'm stumped as to where to go from there.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you show how you add radiobuttons to the list?

Comment: it's ASP.NET, so the RadioButtons are declared in an HTML file.  For instance,

`<asp:RadioButtonList ID="favoriteFruits" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>Apple</asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem>Banana</asp:ListItem> </asp:RadioButtonList>`

Comment: @JayFrizzle have you seen my suggested solution? With that you can keep on adding enum items without worrying about adding items to your RadioButtonList. Then you just need to add `case` statements in your switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can reference the indices as an enumerated value?

Based on your entire post it seems that, "you need to know what is clicked and take action(s) based on that". It really doesn't matter then if you will be testing against the index or the value of the control. If that's the case then doing the following should help:

```
// declare the items, no need to set values
public enum FavoriteFruits {
    Banana,
    Apple, }

// bind the enum to the control
RadioButtonList1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FavoriteFruits)); 
RadioButtonList1.DataBind();

// this is needed because SelectedValue gives you a string...
var selectedValue = (FavoriteFruits)Enum.Parse(typeof(FavoriteFruits), 
   RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue, true); 
//...then you can do a switch against your enum
switch (selectedValue )
{
    case FavoriteFruits.Apple:
        doStuffForApple();
        break;
    case FavoriteFruits.Banana:
       doStuffForBanana();
       break;
}
```

Make sure to validate the `SelectedValue` as it will throw an exception if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you would use enums?

```
enum Fruits{
    Apple = 0,
    Banana = 1,
    Pineapple = 2,
    Pomegranate = 3
};

switch( favoriteFruits.SelectedIndex ){
    case Fruits.Apple:
        doStuffForApple();
    break;
```

Comment: This is better than what I have (no solution), but it's a tad less than optimal.  If I add a new RadioButton to the list, I will also have to add an enum and add the correct index.  This is definitely an idea worth considering, though

Comment: How dynamic you need it to be, where you want to make the change to add more items? you would still have to modify the swicth case wont you?